# How to check fans and voltage on Dell XPS 13?

Tags: dell, fan, fancontrol, sensors, lm-sensors

I own a Dell XPS 13 9360 in which I run Ubuntu 18.04.
I haven't found a way to check the fan's speed and the laptop's voltage.
I installed psensors and lm-sensors, but nothing is shown for both. I also tried several gnome extensions that should show these values -> nothing.
I also gave

```
$ sensors-detect
```

and said YES to any check. Then I gave

```
$ sensors
pch_skylake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +49.5°C  

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +25.0°C  (crit = +107.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter

Package id 0:  +60.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +60.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +57.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

My feel is that some module is missing/not loaded from the kernel. Do you know how to tackle this?

Thank you! :)

Comment: Dear Jimmy, no one has replied to you so far. I felt sorry for that, so I tried to provide an answer to you.
I found that you need to load dell_smm_hwmon kernel module in order to detect the fan speed:

$ sudo modprobe dell_smm_hwmon

I'm still looking for a way to detect the voltage.